# Rally Queries: Pulling Results From Objects

Tags: object, rally, testcase

I am still having trouble pulling results from the objects that I query.
The query below pulls all TestCase objects and prints them to screen. The objects look like this: `[object, Object]`.

I tried to then refine it by printing `document.write( queryResults.testcase.Results + " " + i);` but it then prints this: `undefined #` (# increments with index)

My ultimate goal here is to be able to find test cases that have not been run, AKA, have no result. My strategy, as suggested by another poster, was to return all the test cases, and then sort for Result.length=0; (meaning there are no results).
 I tried `document.write( queryResults.testcase.Results.length + " " + i);` but that didn't work, nothing prints to the screen at all. I tried a similar thing with Results[i], thinking it was an array of objects.
I tried playing around with 'fetch', but it only seems to return something when I leave it blank (default is true, which returns all fields).

```
function runMainQuery(rallyDataSource) {
        document.getElementById("TestCaseInfo").innerHTML = "";
        busySpinner = new rally.sdk.ui.basic.Wait({hideTarget: false});
        busySpinner.display('spinner');
        var daySpan = numOfDays; // how many days back from today for TestCaseResult inclusion

        var dateBoundingClause = '(Date >= "' + previousDate(daySpan) + '")';

       // ORIGINAL VALUE ------  var dateBoundingClause = '(Date >= "' + previousDate(daySpan) + '")';

        querySpec = {
            key   : "testcase",
            type  : "testcase"
            //query: dateBoundingClause
        };
        rallyDataSource.findAll(querySpec, showResults);
    }//end runMainQuery


    function showResults(queryResults) {
        busySpinner.hide();
        //console.log("Number of test cases returned by the Test Case/Test Case Results query: " +
        //             queryResults.testcase.length);

        totalNumTestCases = queryResults.testcase.length;

        if (queryResults.testcase.length === 0) {
            var message = "Enter the date range (Oldest to Newest). Click UPDATE, and wait for the test cases to populate. Once test cases appear, click GENERATE REPORT.";
            document.getElementById("TestCaseInfo").innerHTML = message;

            return;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < queryResults.testcase.length; i++) {
        document.write( queryResults.testcase + " " + i);
        document.write("<br/>");
        }
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

p.s. I am quite new to stack overflow. I assume there is a way to relate this post to my previous post, but I didn't know how to do that. Please inform me of the proper posting etiquette for related posts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend querying for all Test Cases for which LastVerdict is null, since LastVerdict is only populated if the Test Case has associated Test Case Results. In your code this would look like:

```
    var queryClause = "(LastVerdict = \"\")";
    querySpec = {
        key   : "testcase",
        type  : "testcase",
        query: queryClause
    };
```

This query should return all "not-yet-run" Test Cases. Then you would process the resulting list in your `showResults` function.

Comment: Also - to clarify - the reason that you're not seeing a Results collection on the TestCases being returned is that you haven't specified that it be returned via a fetch. To do this, you'd include a fetch clause in your querySpec. `fetch: "FormattedID,Results,LastVerdict"`.